# Apply color to row on select w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

If I have a selector with drop-down options, how can I change a color of all cells in this row on change?

```
function changeColor(){

}

$(".mySelector").change(function() {
    changeColor();
});

<table>
<tr>
    <td>val 1</td>
    <td>val 2</td>
    <td>
    <select class="mySelector">
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="grn">green</option>
        <option value="blu">blue</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>val 3</td>
    <td>val 4</td>
    <td>
    <select class="mySelector">
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="grn">green</option>
        <option value="blu">blue</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the nearest `<tr>` ancestor of your `<select>` element:

```
$(".mySelector").change(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color",
        $("option:selected", this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your option values to valid colors instead of abbreviations, then you can do this:

```
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
```

JS:

```
$(".mySelector").change(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", this.value);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A2FFT/

If you want to make sure the color gets set on initialization, you can chain another `change` call to it.:

```
$(".mySelector").change(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", this.value);
}).change(); //Set background color without needing to change the selected option.
```